# why is mouseup event not firing when releasing outside div in this react code (using window.addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

Anyone able to highlight why the mouseup event is not firing when I click on the inside div, drag cursor (with mouse button still down) to outside the div's, then release the button?  Failure also seems somewhat intermittent.

This is a react web app.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends React.Component {

  public handleMouseDown = (e:any) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('handleMouseDown - add Listeners')      
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, true)
  }

  public handleMouseUp = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('handleMouseUp - remove Listeners')      
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, true);
  };  

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ border: '1px solid blue', height:300, padding:50 }} >
        Main Div - Top
        <div 
          style={{ border: '1px solid black', height:100 }}
          onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        >
          Inside Div
        </div>        
        Main Div - Bottom
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Debug output:

```
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
handleMouseUp - remove Listeners
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
handleMouseUp - remove Listeners
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
handleMouseDown - add Listeners
```

Comment: Tested this on Mac OS Chrome and worked just fine. Maybe state your browser and OS?

Comment: I've had the same issue on a couple of PC's - I'll try again through...

Comment: reboot/restart- still an issue in Chrome (using VSCode by the way)

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu firefox 64.0. It works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out when dragging mouse from Inside Div to Outside, text was selected and moved together. This changed behaviour of mouse event. I tried putting `user-select: none;` to `.app`'s css and it works properly. Take a look at my code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
   this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
  }
  handleMouseDown(e){
    console.log('handleMouseDown - add Listeners')      
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, true)
  }

  handleMouseUp(e) {
    console.log('handleMouseUp - remove Listeners')      
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, true);
  } 
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ border: '1px solid blue', height:300, padding:50 }} >
        Main Div - Top
        <div style={{ border: '1px solid black', height:100 }} onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>  Inside Divn </div>
        Main Div - Bottom
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: that fixed it for me thanks - do you understand why this works?

Comment: @Greg as I explained, when you dragging in your div, text inside it was being moved as well, so it changed behaviour of `mouseup` event. So when prevent text being selected by using `user-select: none;`, it works properly.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you attach the event separately:

```
onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
```

Comment: I've seen the pattern I'm using on a couple of website and was just following - would still be interested in understanding why it's not working for me... e.g. is there a fundamental issue with the concept? (e.g. https://blog.usejournal.com/mastering-drag-drop-with-reactjs-part-01-39bed3d40a03)